# Generating sequence number in mongoDB

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, mongodb-java, jdoql

I am using java,Datanucleus,mongodb and JDO in my project.

I have a requirement where I should generate sequence number and store it in DB.
I was going through various links and found that  DataNucleus supports the automatic assignment of sequence values for object identities only for the following datastore:-

```
Oracle
PostgreSQL
SAP DB
DB2
Firebird
HSQLDB
H2
Derby (from v10.6)
DB4O
```

So does that mean -> sequence generation can't be done for mongoDB? If it can be then please provide some useful link  or guidance !

Note:I am already aware of the fact that mongoDB creates an object id on its own..but I want custom sequence number generation,store it in DB and use it.

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus-MongoDB supports "INCREMENT" value strategy, as stated [very clearly in the docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/datastore_features.html), and additionally supports many other strategies.

Comment: thanks..i got it..but is it possible to write custom class to generate "INCREMENT" like its done for sequence in datanucleus?If yes please provide any relevant resource link..

Comment: INCREMENT is defined in the JDO spec as being provided by the JDO implementation, not by some custom classes.